# How to handle a product approval system for an online c2c marketplace?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, prisma, marketplace

I am building an online marketplace and am trying to figure out the best way to handle all the different states a product listing could be.

Requirements:

- Has to handle product `approval/pending/denial`
- Allow the seller to set their listings as `public/active` or `private/inactive`

Current schema: *non-relevant info not included for simplicity

```
model Product {
  status: APPROVED | PENDING | DENIED
  active: Boolean
}
```

Here's some context:

- Approved Active Product

  - `status` = `APPROVED`
  - `active` = `true`
- Approved Inactive Product

  - `status` = `APPROVED`
  - `active` = `false`

---

- Pending Active Product

  - `status` = `DENIED`
  - `active` = `true`
- Pending Inactive Product

  - `status` = `DENIED`
  - `active` = `false`

---

- Denied Active Product

  - `status` = `DENIED`
  - `active` = `true`
- Denied Inactive Product

  - `status` = `DENIED`
  - `active` = `false`

I think this is the best way to handle the system but would love some feedback.

Also considered this:

```
model Product {
  active: Boolean
  pendingApproval: Boolean
  approved: Boolean
}
```

I think this just overcomplicates the logic that is achieved in the first system.

Comment: Do you need alternatives on how could this system be modelled? Are you facing any issues in this current implementation?

Comment: @NurulSundarani Just wondering if anyone else has a solution that accomplishes this for them. We are still building our platform and just trying to get all the info we can early on so we don't have to make large changes later on.